# Simple UPDATE query takes too much time in InnoDB than MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

**Quick description:**

In my application (VC++/Windows 8) I am issuing simple update queries to increase value of a field in a InnoDB table in MySQL database. It takes way too long than the same with MyISAM table.

**Details:**

I am creating a table `DEMO_TABLE` having columns `MyID` and `MyCounter` (both integers) and engine `MyISAM`

```
pStatement->execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO_TABLE(MyID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, MyCounter int) ENGINE=MyISAM");
```

I then added to the table a row having MyID value equal to 0. Then I am issuing UPDATE query in a loop:

```
time_t dwTime1 = time(&dwTime1);
for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
{
    char strUpdateRequest[256];
    sprintf_s(strUpdateRequest, 256, "UPDATE DEMO_TABLE SET MyCounter = (MyCounter + 1) WHERE ThreadID = 0");
    pStatement->executeUpdate(strUpdateRequest);
}
time_t dwTime2 = time(&dwTime2);
std::cout << "\nTime difference: " << (dwTime2 - dwTime1);
```

It ran quickly and the output was:

> Time difference: 0

Means it has consumed less than a second.

But when I deleted table and repeated all this exercise again with `InnoDB` engine.

```
pStatement->execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO_TABLE(ThreadID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, MyCounter int) ENGINE=InnoDB");
```

However, this time to my surprise it took much longer and the output was:

> Time difference: 17

It has consumed 17 seconds.

(Despite, in both the cases above I checked table containts and found `MyCounter` column value has been populated correctly (500))

**UPDATE:**

I also have observed there is lot of disk activity in these 17 seconds.

**Question:**

In many discussions and even in MySQL documents it has been mentioned that in case of updates InnoDB performs much better than MyISAM. But I observed exactly opposite.

Can someone please clarify this behavior? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090395/difference-in-required-time-to-insert-innodb-myisam-records?rq=1

Comment: You probably need to commit each update or enable `autocommit` in your library. Also, check with a larger number of updates e.g. 10,000 and on multiple rows simultaneously. InnoDB benefits a lot from having row-level locks as opposed to MyISAM's table-level locking and here you are handling just one row in your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was here in my.ini (which can be located in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 or similar folder based on installation)

There is parameter `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` which has value defaulted to zero causing 1 MB of `innodb_log_buffer_size` to be written to disk at each commit. This was resulting in major performance penalty.

So I made `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` after reading its description and then restarted MySQL server, then performance boosted a lot.

> If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
>   disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
>   willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
>   transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
>   logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
>   the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
>   means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
>   file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```